# Symfony2 Doctrine query - datetime addition

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I currently am facing a little problem : I have a table of events, and would like to get which events are upcoming or ongoing.

So for instance we are on a Monday at 12:00, we have 3 events planned for today :

- Event A starting at 10:00 and lasting 1h
- Event B starting at 11:00 and lasting 2h
- Event C starting at 13:00 and lasting 2h

In the end I would like to get Event B (ongoing) and Event C (upcoming).

I tried doing this (didn't work) :

```
public function findAllPast(\Datetime $datetime) 
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('event')
        ->where('event.startTime + event.duration >= :time')
        ->setParameter('time', $datetime)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();    
}
```

Searching around, I came onto the SQL ADDTIME() function. I'd pretty much like to do a where('ADDTIME(event.startTime, event.duration) >= :time'), but this isn't recognized by Doctrine.

Is there any proper way of doing this without brutal native SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Doctrine's `DATE_ADD()` function :

```
public function findAllPast(\Datetime $datetime) 
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('event')
        ->where('DATE_ADD(event.startTime, event.duration, "days") >= :time')
        ->setParameter('time', $datetime)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();    
}
```

This supposes that `event.duration` is in days, of course.

**EDIT** : Alternative in PHP working with `DateTime` objects

If `$duration` is in seconds, you can simply :

```
$datetime->sub(new DateInterval('PT' . $durationInSeconds . 'S')); // or ->add(), depending on what you wnat
```

and then just use :

```
public function findAllPast(\Datetime $datetime) 
{

    $datetime->sub(new DateInterval('PT' . $durationInSeconds . 'S'));

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('event')
        ->where('event.startTime >= :time')
        ->setParameter('time', $datetime)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the kind of thing I'm looking for. Now, the 'duraton' field is of time type in my database, so I'd need to convert it to seconds. Is there some way to modify the event.duration field, as in setting it as a parameter and doing something akin to ->setParameter('duration', strtotime($duration)) ?

Comment: Your `duration` field should not be a time type, since it's an interval. You should store it as an int (in seconds then). And your problem is solved ;)

Comment: You're right, I'm going to change this. Thanks for all !

Comment: Welp, DATE_ADD() only supports days and months :(

Comment: Well, you can `$duration = $duration / 86400` and use `"days"` as a trick ;) — See my updated answer

Comment: Aye, thing is most of my durations are under a day. I would like to be able to tell which events are ongoing in 'real time',

Comment: Oh so doctrine can do a date_add() with not integer days ?

Comment: Tried it, seems like it rounds up the day number

Comment: Too bad, you need to go the PHP route then, see updated answer ;)

Comment: Hm, thing is the duration depends on the event. I'm currently trying to do something with raw SQL, since it does have an addtime() function, though it's much for "barbaric" than DQL.

Comment: Another option may be to use [beberlei/doctrineextensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions), which allows the use of [TIMESTAMPADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) in query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's a working solution with $duration as a time field (much simpler for the form part of the problem) : a custom query

```
   $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('Ormindo\EventBundle\Entity\Event', 'event');

    $sql = " 
    SELECT *
      FROM events
      WHERE ADDTIME(startTime, duration) > '" . $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ."'"
    ;

    $query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    return $query->getResult();
```

don't forget to use

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder;
```

Thank you tchap for your time and quick replies :)

Comment: No problem ! Consider upvoting my answer if it helped ;) And accept your own answer too